# How to get download campaigns data from Adwords API

Tags: google-api, google-ads

I am trying to download report data using API for adgroup_performance_report. I get all the campaigns etc in the report except download campaigns. How do I get about that? What am I missing?

Details:

AWQL query:

```
SELECT Date,HourOfDay, AdGroupId, AdGroupName,AdNetworkType1, CampaignId, CampaignName, Impressions, Clicks, Cost FROM ADGROUP_PERFORMANCE_REPORT DURING YESTERDAY
```

API: v201609

Language: Python

More:
Download campaigns: Not sure if they are download campaigns but they have a down arrow button where normally it's search and video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The campaign type you are referring to are the Universal App Campaigns (UAC). For reporting, UAC statistics can be found in the following reports mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/mobile-app-campaigns#reporting). Currently, however, the AdvertisingChannelType and AdvertisingChannelSubType fields are not available in the Adgroup Performance Report.

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adwords-api/l2H5E3bvv-g